# What username for Login to Console on a Digital Ocean Droplet running FreeBSD 12

Tags: freebsd, login, digital-ocean

As an alternative to making an ssh connection to your Droplet on [DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean), they offer a "Console" which is a [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) connection, akin to plugging a monitor and keyboard into your virtual server.

When opening such a Console window, I am prompted for a `login` and then `password`.

Having created my Droplet with a SSH key, I do not know what the `login` might be, nor what the `password` might be.

➥ How does one login via the Console to a Droplet on DigitalOcean?

My Droplet is running FreeBSD 12, if that matters.

I have seen the documentation page, [*How to Regain Access to Droplets using the DigitalOcean Droplet Console*](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/resources/console/). That page does have a section *Log In with the Console*. But little explanation of the login name or password is given. It mentions:

> At the login prompt, enter the user you want to log in as. This will typically be the root user or a user configured with sudo privileges.

But for my new FreeBSD droplet, `root` did not work as a login name.

If I use the `freebsd` user, I am stuck at the prompt for a password. There is no password established, so Catch-22.

```bash
login: freebsd
Password: 
Login incorrect
login:
```

…and on it goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

On your Droplet admin page, *Access* tab, click `Reset Root Password` button to establish a password for the `root` user on your FreeBSD system.

## Details

By default neither of your given users on FreeBSD, `freebsd` & `root`, have a password established. This effectively disables remote logins via SSH, good for security.

Your use of SSH keys automatically logs you in as either user.

```bash
ssh freebsd@123.123.123.123
```

…or…

```bash
ssh root@123.123.123.123
```

If you have not gone out of your way to establish passwords for either user, then you must use the `Reset Root Password` button on the `Access` tab of your Droplet admin page on DigitalOcean.com. This button will create a password for the `root` user on your FreeBSD VM if a password does not exist. If a password does exist, the old will be replaced by a new password.

[image: screenshot of the DigitalOcean.com Droplet administration page, on the Access tab, pointing out the two buttons, "Reset Root User" & "Launch Console".]

After establishing the password, then use the other button on that same panel of the Droplet admin page on `Access` tab: `Launch Console` button. This creates a server-local [shell session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), as if you plugged a keyboard & mouse into the server box. You see the session remotely via a [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) session displayed in your web browser.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/connect-with-ssh/) says that the default username for FreeBSD droplets is `freebsd`.

Comment: But there is no password for the user `freebsd`. So I am stuck at the prompt asking for a password.